# DUVIDA QUERY SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Estou com uma duvida de como proceder neste caso, onde tenho um query que precisaria que o **nserie** fosse ignorado ou que exibisse apenas o 1 item desse

```
SELECT
                ped.codfil,
                i.seqipd,
                i.codpro,
                p.codref,
                i.qtdped,
                i.unimed,
                i.usu_pesbar,
                i.codpro,
                isNull(d.numsep,0) nserie,
                i.codder tamanho,
                i.cplipd,
                i.obsipd,
                p.usu_preven,
                m.sigmoe [Moeda],
                p.usu_moepvs,
                FORMAT(i.preuni, 'N', 'pt-br') vlrunit,
                i.preuni,
                FORMAT(i.vlrliq, 'N', 'pt-br') vlrtotal,
                i.SitIpd,
                i.coddep,
                p.pesbru,
                i.usu_vlrfat,
                ped.usu_forcal,
                i.perdsc,
                i.usu_desapr,
                i.usu_vlrdsc,
                p.ctrsep
            FROM E120PED ped, E075PRO p, E031MOE m, E120IPD i
            LEFT OUTER JOIN E120DLS d
                ON (i.codemp=d.codemp
                    AND i.codfil=d.CodFil
                    AND i.numped=d.numped
                    AND i.seqipd=d.seqipd)
            WHERE ped.codemp=i.codemp
            AND ped.codfil=i.CodFil
            AND ped.numped=i.numped
            AND i.codmoe=m.codmoe
            AND i.codemp=p.codemp
            AND i.codpro=p.codpro
            AND i.codemp=10
            AND i.numped = '709'
            AND i.codfil = '501'

            group by 
            ped.codfil,
                i.seqipd,
                i.codpro,
                p.codref,
                i.qtdped,
                i.unimed,
                i.usu_pesbar,
                i.codpro,
                d.numsep,
                i.codder ,
                i.cplipd,
                i.obsipd,
                p.usu_preven,
                m.sigmoe,
                p.usu_moepvs,
                i.vlrliq,
                i.preuni,                   
                i.SitIpd,
                i.coddep,
                p.pesbru,
                i.usu_vlrfat,
                ped.usu_forcal,
                i.perdsc,
                i.usu_desapr,
                i.usu_vlrdsc,
                p.ctrsep

                ORDER BY i.seqipd DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, quando você diz apenas 1 item desse, você quer dizer o primeiro resultado da tabela E120DLS? Se sim, você pode ao invés de utilizar um LEFT JOIN, fazer um subselect para o campo.

EX:

```
SELECT
            ped.codfil,
            i.seqipd,
            i.codpro,
            p.codref,
            i.qtdped,
            i.unimed,
            i.usu_pesbar,
            i.codpro,
            (SELECT TOP 1 d.numsep FROM E120DLS WHERE ...) as nserie,
```